# The primary key is not always unique in a table

Tags: java, database, entity, primary-key

I have two tables:

- "tableA"

  the primaryKey is column1 and column2
- "tableB"

  primaryKey is also column1 and column2 but additional the column4

-

The Problem is, that the primaryKey of **"tableA"** is not always unique. Then there are more then one results. In this case I have to look in **"tableB"**. The primaryKeyB distinguished in tableB the "more then one results". 
How can I join the two tables with an extended primaryKey like: if the result of findByPkTableA is more then one result, then use the findByPkTableB. Or is it posible to load the column of tableB in tableA ? Or use a SecondaryTable?

The construction of database table:

[image: the construktion of databasetable]

**The code**

primaryKey A

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class PkTableA implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6732213911212534660L;

@Column(name="column_1")
private int column1;

@Column(name="column_2")
private int column2;

//Getter Setter

}
```

primaryKey B

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class PkTableB implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6732213911212534660L;

@Column(name="column_1")
private int column1;

@Column(name="column_2")
private int column2;

@Column(name="column_4")
private int column4;

//Getter Setter

}
```

TableA

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="tableA")
public class TableA {

@EmbeddedId
private PkTableA id;

@Column(name="column_3")
private int column3;

//Getter Setter
}
```

TableB

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="tableB")
public class TableB {

@EmbeddedId
private PkTableB id;

@Column(name="column_5")
private int column5;

//Getter Setter

}
```

Comment: if you define `column1` and `column2` unique in the database you cannot have this problem because the database won't allow an insert for a duplicate primary key

Answer (score 0):

You have some logic problem...

If you declare `primary key (column1, column2)` you cannot have duplicate values because the database won't allow the insert.

```
create table tableA
( column1 int not null,
  column2 int not null,
  column3 int not null,
 primary key (column1, column2));


insert into tableA values
(1,1,1),
(2,2,2),
(1,2,1);
```

We have the following rows in the database:

col1   col2    col3
 1       1       1 
 2       2       2
 1       2       1

if we try to insert the following row:

```
insert into tableA values (1,1,5);
```

We will encounter in a duplicate error

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**EDIT**

The only way to join both tables is

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.* 
FROM
    tableA JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.column1 = tableB.column1 AND
       tableA.column2 = tableB.column2
```

Comment: yes it make sence, but the insert into the tableA and tableB is not from me. I have just read the content of the database and display it. the primaryKey is created for me (in java) to read the contend. i dont want insert into both tables.

Comment: You can join the two tables but you are not guaranteed to have the expected results because on `tableA` an attribute is missing.... (the reference for `column4` of `tableB`)

Comment: if i have an unique Id (PkTableA "column1=1 and column2 = 2") only one time, then it works all fine. In this case there is in tableB no row with this ("column1=1 and column2 = 2"). But any time there is in tableB an input with "column1=1, column2 = 2 and column3 = 1" and "column1=1, column2 = 2 and column3 = 2". That is the point of interest. Now there will be insert (not from me) the double input ("column1=1 and column2 = 2") in tableA. And at this time i have the problem!!!

Comment: I edited my answer adding the only way to do a join on both tables... but as I said before the result may be different from the one you are expecting

Comment: yes it is very complicated. The only unique primaryKey for TableA is tableA.column1 and tableA.column2 and tableB.column4 !

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key that includes multiple columns of different tables... you may what to try the following...

have a generated unique id for tableB and join that into tableA..

create a new entity which includes all the primary key columns of tableA and join column of tableB

```
    public class PrimaryKeyEntity 
    {
         private  string column1;
         private string column2;
         private pkTabelB joincolumnfromB;
   }
```

Then in your tableA entity include this as idclass...

```
 @IdClass(PrimaryKeyEntity.class)
 @Entity
 @Table(name="tableA")
 public class TableA {.....
 @Embedded
 PkTableB pkTableB
```

Comment: o.k., but how should i join the "joincolumnfromB"

Comment: I think we can embed the pktableB in table one and modify  public class PrimaryKeyEntity 
    {
         private  string column1;
         private string column2;
         private PkTableB pktbaleB;
   } ...